# Using jQuery to set CSS attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

First ever post to Stackoverflow and coding newb. I have seen many a example in which people have successfully set CSS attributes using jQuery. However, after many frustrating hours, I have still yet to see what obvious thing is wrong. Here's my very simplified code. I know that if I add this attribute manually to the CSS, it has the desired effect. However, I cannot get it to work using jQuery. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated. I feel as if this should be so obvious but I don't see it.

I am using RoR (and I have included //=require jquery in app.js)

CSS

```
    #magicaldiv{
                margin-left: -175px;
                margin-top: -20px;
                width:350px;
                height:40px;
                position:absolute;}
```

JS

```
     var buttonPointer = $('#magicaldiv');
     $(document).ready(updatePointer);
     $(window).resize(updatePointer); 
     function updatePointer(){
                              buttonPointer.css('left', 200);}
```

I have also tried several iterations of jQuery and JS including but not limited to..

JS

```
     document.getElementById("magicaldiv").style.left = 200;
```

and

```
     var left = 200 + "px";
     buttonPointer.css('left', left);
```

and

```
     buttonPointer.css('left', '200px');
```

even though the documentation suggests that all numbers will be turned into a string and assumed to be px.

Comment: Welcome! Please show us the html.  It could be as simple as an incorrect ID on the div element you are attempting to apply the style to!

Comment: Are you sure that `magicaldiv` exists when you define `buttonPointer`? If the javascript is loaded before the html, and you don't wrap that in a `document.ready` call, it won't work.

Comment: @flyingL123 - that was my next comment as well.  Your script either needs to be in the footer of your page, OR it needs to be wrapped like so: `jQuery(function($) { .... your script here ... });` - which is called a [document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.

Comment: @itsgoingdown - not true / accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to wrap the `buttonPointer` definition in a `document.ready` call, depending on the order of your source code.

```
var buttonPointer;
function updatePointer(){
  buttonPointer.css('left', 200);}

$(document).ready(function() {
  buttonPointer = $('#magicaldiv');
  updatePointer();
});

$(window).resize(updatePointer);
```

Comment: So my basic understanding was that anything above the yield would load before all js. Clearly I was wrong. THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO.